# Flutter: onTapDown function not always called

Tags: flutter, dart, game-engine, flame

I'm new in flutter development. I add onTapdown listener if i perform any clicked action on the screen. It's worked,but the problem is sometime when i clicked,onTapdown function not get called.I don't know what problem i have done.Hope can help me solve this problem.Thank you in advance.

```
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flame/components/parallax_component.dart';
import 'package:flame/util.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    Util flameUtil = Util();

  await flameUtil.fullScreen();
  runApp(MyGame(flameUtil).widget);
}

class MyGame extends BaseGame {
  MyGame(Util flameUtil) {

    final images = [

      ParallaxImage("space/bg_base.png",repeat: ImageRepeat.repeat,fill: LayerFill.height),
      ParallaxImage("space/bg_big_star.png",repeat: ImageRepeat.repeatY,fill: LayerFill.height),
      ParallaxImage("space/bg_planet.png",repeat: ImageRepeat.repeat,fill: LayerFill.none),

    ];

    var game = Squres(images);

    add(game);

    TapGestureRecognizer tapper = TapGestureRecognizer();
    tapper.onTapDown = game.onTapDown;
    flameUtil.addGestureRecognizer(tapper);
  }
}

class Squres extends ParallaxComponent{

    Squres(List<ParallaxImage> images) : super(images){
      baseSpeed = const Offset(4,0);
      layerDelta = const Offset(0,-50);
    }

    @override
    void render(Canvas canvas) {    
      super.render(canvas);
    }

    @override
    void resize(Size size) {
      super.resize(size);
    }

    @override
    void update(double t) {
      super.update(t);
    }

    //not always trigger
    void onTapDown(TapDownDetails tap){
        print("trigger");
    }

  }
```

Comment: your onTapDown function has a parameter, why aren't you passing any when you are calling it?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use flame 0.22.0^ and use create your game class like this instead:

```
class MyGame extends BaseGame with TapDetector {
  Squres game;

  MyGame() {    
    final images = [
      ParallaxImage("space/bg_base.png",repeat: ImageRepeat.repeat,fill: LayerFill.height),
      ParallaxImage("space/bg_big_star.png",repeat: ImageRepeat.repeatY,fill: LayerFill.height),
      ParallaxImage("space/bg_planet.png",repeat: ImageRepeat.repeat,fill: LayerFill.none),
    ];
    game = Squres(images);

    add(game);
  }

  @override
  void onTapDown(TapUpDetails details) {
    print("trigger");
    game.onTapDown(details);
  }
}
```

Also, remember that you don't have to override `update`, `resize` and `render` if you only call super on them.